# An error occurs when creating a spring project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

[image: Error]

error code:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Could not initialize class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.PropertiesConverter
Spring just laid out, ran. The Java version is 16SE and the tomcat version is 7.
```

In addition, when creating a maven project through the spring legacy project, pressing finish does not cause any reaction. And it doesn't generate.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, you are using Spring 3.2 (which is ancient) with an incompatible JDK.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: Check your error logs (as the screenshot says) to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Also the fact that you cannot create a regular maven project looks like you have some connectivity issues.

Answer (score 0):

It should be **Java 11**.

Spring MVC Project working. (Spring Legacy Project)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFlkV.png)